# Make a div clickable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to dynamically make divs that are clickable.  I have inserted a test function.  The test function runs even though the div has not been clicked.

```
  function displayResults(responseTxt)
  { 
        var results = document.getElementById("results");
        jsonObj = eval ("(" + responseTxt + ")");
        var length = jsonObj.response.artists.length;
        results.innerHTML = "Please click on an artist for more details: "
        
        for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            var entry = document.createElement("div");
            var field = document.createElement("fieldset");
            
            entry.id = i;
            entry.innerHTML = i + 1 + ". " + jsonObj.response.artists[i].name; 
            field.appendChild(entry);
            results.appendChild(field);
            //entry.addEventListener("click", idSearch(jsonObj.response.artists[i].id), false);
            entry.addEventListener("click", test(), false);
            
        } 
  } // end function displayResults          
  
  function test()
  {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "tested";
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `test()` function and passing its return value to `.addEventListener()`. Remove the parentheses:

```
entry.addEventListener("click", test, false);
```

So that you pass the function itself to `.addEventListener()`.

That answers the question as asked, but to anticipate your next problem, for the line you've got commented out you'd do this:

```
entry.addEventListener("click",
                       function() {
                          idSearch(jsonObj.response.artists[i].id);
                       }, false);
```

That is, create an anonymous function to pass to `.addEventListener()` where the anonymous function knows how to call your `idSearch()` function with parameters. Except that won't work because when the event is actually triggered `i` will have the value from the end of the loop. You need to add an extra function/closure so that the individual values of `i` are accessible:

```
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {        
        var entry = document.createElement("div");
        var field = document.createElement("fieldset");

        entry.id = i;
        entry.innerHTML = i + 1 + ". " + jsonObj.response.artists[i].name; 
        field.appendChild(entry);
        results.appendChild(field);
        // add immediately-invoked anonymous function here:
        (function(i) {
            entry.addEventListener("click",
                               function() {
                                  idSearch(jsonObj.response.artists[i].id);
                               }, false);
        })(i);
    }
```

That way the `i` in `jsonObj.response.artists[i].id` is actually going to be the parameter `i` from the anonymous function which is the individual value of `i` from the loop at the time each iteration ran.